# How to link identity_claim_appid_g to an app registration display name in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm running a query in Azure Log Analytics to list which identities have read a secret from keyvault:

```
AzureDiagnostics
    | where ResourceType == "VAULTS"
    | order by TimeGenerated desc
    | where OperationName == "SecretGet"
    | project   identity_claim_appid_g,  
                identity_claim_http_schemas_microsoft_com_identity_claims_objectidentifier_g,  
                identity_claim_http_schemas_xmlsoap_org_ws_2005_05_identity_claims_upn_s,  
                identity_claim_xms_mirid_s
```

The `identity_claim_appid_g` column contains the id of a registered application but is it possible to show the display name in the query results as well?

Comment: Do you know that the name of identity_claim_appid_g is in which table? If you know that, you can use join operator to do that.

Comment: I'm hoping it's that simple, but I can't find which table it's in

Comment: Do you know the name via the id(identity_claim_appid_g)?

Comment: How do you mean? When I add `id(identity_claim_appid_g)` I get an error: Unknown function: 'id'.

Comment: sorry for misleading. I mean do you know the real name, since you know identity_claim_appid_g.

Comment: Yes, I know it by looking it up in AAD

Comment: if you know the name and its related identity_claim_appid_g, you can do it using hard-code as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked for, but for personal users you can use

identity_claim_unique_name_s

Answer (score 0):

Just to say that you can now use identity_claim_xms_mirid_s to retrieve the caller ID from Entra.

So to sort what you were looking for you can now use...

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider =="MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT"
| extend SplitAll = split(identity_claim_xms_mirid_s, '/')  
| extend Caller=SplitAll[-1]  
| summarize count() by tostring(Caller)
| sort by count_
```